# Trying to make my first ajax, but stuck on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I'm trying to make my first AJAX web tool.  Javascript is my kryptonite though.  I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, but any help would be great!

```
function MyFunc() {
  var xmlhttp;
  var type = getElementById("type");
  var agency = getElementById("agency");
  var location = document.getElementById("location");
  location = location.options[location.selectedIndex].value;
  type = type.checked;
  agency = agency.checked;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
 else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET","view.php?location=" + location + "&type=" + type + "&agency=" + agency,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
     document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
 }
//       setTimeout(refresh, 300000);
}
```

You can see the "live" site at tol1dc.homedns.org  On the "Job Searcher" page (http://tol1dc.homedns.org/modules/navigator/navto.php?unique_ID=3)

Now I'm really clueless about Javascript. I don't know if this should be in the head of the document, or if it's ok in the body?

Also you can see the "setTimeout" I'm trying to get the page to auto reload the table every 5 minutes.

I don't really know what problem I'm getting either, just that it's not responding.  I can't see a connect attempt on my server logs, I couldn't get the button to even do a document.write("hello world");

Your help would be greatly appreciated if you can get me on the right track!

Thanks

Comment: I have to ask the obvious question; is your web browser allowing javascript?

Comment: I believe so.  I am able to run the Javascript examples on w3schools.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( ` on `/modules/navigator/navto.php?unique_ID=3:38`  What web browser are you using?  You should check your debugger (F12 in IE, firebug in Firefox, etc.)  That means your line `var xmlhttp;` is incomplete.  You need to assign the variable.

Comment: V21 of Firefox for Linux
Ok, is it ok to update in the body, or do i need to put it in the head?  (baby steps)

Comment: If you are using Firefox, you will need to install firebug (it is an add-on to firefox.  Open a browser window, and in the URL, type `about:addons`

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the "Hello World" working.  I've got Firebug already, sorry what am I looking for with  Firebug?

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore where the javascript is located.  It will execute anywhere.  Usually, I like to load it as early in the page as possible, so that it is available on long pages.  Others prefer the opposite, to make sure all elements are already loaded before execution.

Comment: Ok, that's great news.  Think that was my number 1 hangup on Javascript, never knowing where to put it.

Comment: Thanks Sable, now that I know where in Firebug to look, I managed to get that sorted!  Looks awesome.  Would love to give you the Tick for helping with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A syntax error is occurring on line 38.

Do you mean?

```
var type = document.getElementById("type");
var agency = document.getElementById("agency");
```

Noting the variable assignment and calling the getElementById function of the document object.

The location of the code in the markup is fine, but it might be cleaner to either place it at the bottom of the body (last thing before ) or in the head. Also, wrapping it in window's on load event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Grab input and AJAX.
}
```